# Display the button in the page only for 15 minutes in UWP applicatiom

Tags: timer, uwp, windows-store-apps, win-universal-app

I want to display the button only for fifteen minutes in the page irrespective of the application is closed or not.I have tried with the dispatcher timer but it's time got reset every time when the application is launched. Is there any way to achieve this?

Comment: You could store the initial start time then compare the offset of that in the timer, so if the stored time is more than 15 minutes ago then don't display button then with outer check for that time too so don't start timer either, something like that might work?

Answer (score 2):

You can use LocalSettings:

```
public sealed partial class MainPage : Page
{

    private const string _timestampKey = "timestamp";

    public MainPage()
    {
        this.InitializeComponent();
    }

    protected override void OnNavigatedTo(NavigationEventArgs e)
    {
        base.OnNavigatedTo(e);
        Windows.Storage.ApplicationDataContainer localSettings = Windows.Storage.ApplicationData.Current.LocalSettings;

        DateTime started;

        if (localSettings.Values.ContainsKey(_timestampKey))
        {
            started = DateTime.ParseExact(localSettings.Values[_timestampKey].ToString(), "O", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
        }
        else
        {
            started = DateTime.Now;
            localSettings.Values[_timestampKey] = started.ToString("O");
        }

        System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("First launch: " + started.ToString("O"));
    }
}
```

And then just use DispathcerTimer as you did before.

Answer (score 0):

@user37779 have a good way to do it . I think I can use Storyboard to make the button hide in 15 minutes.

I should write a xaml.

```
    <Button Name="Button" Margin="10,10,10,10" Content="123"></Button>
```

And I will write a storyboard in code.

```
  public MainPage()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        var storyboard = new Storyboard();
        var animation = new ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames();
        animation.KeyFrames.Add(new DiscreteObjectKeyFrame()
        {
            KeyTime = new KeyTime(),
            Value = Visibility.Collapsed
        });
        Storyboard.SetTarget(animation, Button);
        Storyboard.SetTargetProperty(animation, "Visibility");
        animation.EnableDependentAnimation = true;
        storyboard.BeginTime=TimeSpan.FromMinutes(15);
        storyboard.Children.Add(animation);
        storyboard.Completed += Storyboard_Completed;
        storyboard.Begin();
    }
```

Comment: @JustinXL If close the app that will close the button.

Comment: @JustinXL Try use user3777939 and my way.

Answer (score 0):

Save elapsed time to `Windows.Storage.ApplicationData.Current.LocalSettings` when `Suspended` event is occurring. When application is resuming or launching -> read previous time from settings and start from it.

For ex.: user spend 7 minutes and close application -> you save this value to the settings. When user starts app -> you read previous value (7 minutes) and start timer (wait 8 minutes).